# SQLAlchemy cannot connect to Mysql server on localhost in Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, flask, kubernetes, flask-sqlalchemy, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed a mysql service in Kubernetes and created a database(db1) and a custom user('foo'@'localhost' identified by 'bar') with all privileges. I can verify it.

but somehow my Flask application cannot connect to it. So, I turned on the debug mode and got

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Address not available)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

This never happens in Linux machines. This is my DATABASE_URL `mysql+pymysql://foo:bar@localhost:3306/db1`
Is there anything I am doing wrong? I am new to kubernetes, I don't even know how to go about debugging it. Please let me know if I am not providing enough information.

Thank you.

---

[EDITED]

mysql-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mysql
    labels:
        app: mysql
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: mysql
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: mysql
        spec:
            containers:
                - image: mysql:5.6
                  name: mysql
                  env:
                    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                      value: "123"
                  ports:
                    - containerPort: 3306
                      name: mysql
                  volumeMounts:
                    - name: mysql-persistent-storage
                      mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            volumes:
                - name: mysql-persistent-storage
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                    claimName: mysql-volumeclaim
```

mysql-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: mysql
    labels:
        app: mysql
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
        - port: 3306
    selector:
        app: mysql
```

Comment: Hi @pizza, do you use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql)? If the answer is yes please take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/issues/129) and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679208/unable-to-connect-to-cloudsql-from-kubernetes-engine-cant-connect-to-mysql-ser/51711483). Did you follow any tutorial?

Comment: Hi @Jakub I use a mysql container. I just read a tutorial on how to deploy a word press app with mysql and I was just trying to deploy my simple flask application with mysql as an exercise. After I deploy mysql with clusterIP, I can exec into it and see the database and the user I created. But when I try to get my flask app to connect to the mysql server, just the way I would do in Linux, I get that error. I have no idea what could be possibly wrong, or whether it is my flask config or kubernetes. Any idea or suggestions ?

Comment: Hey are you trying to connect to mysql in the same pod? are they different pods? if that so why are you trying to use localhost

Comment: @paltaa oh yeah. They are in different pods. I am new to kubernetes so didn't notice that. Thanks. Could I ask then how to connect to myql on a different pod?

Comment: Could you post your mysql deployment + service ?

Comment: You should connect  to the service:service-port

Comment: @paltaa I updated my original post.  you mean I connect to ```mysql+pymysql://foo:bar@mysql:3306/db1```?

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: @pizza- Did fix your issue? , I got the same issue with postgresql , glad to know how do you fix it !